# Android Kotlin-Navigation between fragments not working when there is a bottom navigation bar present

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to navigate between two fragments- Home an Edit Profile (using buttons). While my code for the navigation bar work, when I click on the button to navigate to Edit Profile, navigation doesn't happen.
HomeFragment.kt

```
package com.example.profilepagenavigation.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.example.profilepagenavigation.R
import com.example.profilepagenavigation.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val button = view?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button?.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_notifications_to_editProfile)
        }

        val textView: TextView = binding.textHome
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }
        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

EditProfile.kt

```
package com.example.profilepagenavigation

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController


class EditProfile : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false)
        val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button2)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_editProfile_to_navigation_notifications)
        }
        return view
    }


            }
```

MainActvity.kt

```
package com.example.profilepagenavigation

import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.profilepagenavigation.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```

Navigation graph ->

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        android:name="com.example.profilepagenavigation.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        android:name="com.example.profilepagenavigation.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
        android:label="@string/title_notifications"
        android:name="com.example.profilepagenavigation.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notifications">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_notifications_to_editProfile"
            app:destination="@id/editProfile" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/editProfile"
        android:label="fragment_edit_profile"
        android:name="com.example.profilepagenavigation.EditProfile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_edit_profile">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_editProfile_to_navigation_notifications"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I think there is a mistake in the Main Activity code or Home Fragment code. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not using View Binding right, correct way is here:

If you using like that in all fragments you don't have that problems

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_editProfile)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on binding.message - message appears in red and error is :Unresolved reference: message

Comment: And also there is no reference to the button being clicked here? Can you explain?

Comment: Also please let me know if the above code will not overwrite my bottom nav bar capabilities?

Comment: In your case you can use `binding.button2` in here, it's supporting your bottom nav bar capabilities there is no problem for bottom nav it's not overwriting.

Comment: Also, you should be use navigation graph as Bincy said

Comment: Thank you! I am now able to navigate as expected!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is there in the navigation graph and in the button click

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:label="@string/title_home"
    android:name="com.example.profilepagenavigation.ui.home.HomeFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_editProfile"
        app:destination="@id/editProfile" />
</fragment>
```

As you navigate from HomeFragment to EditProfile fragment, you must add an action inside HomeFragment. And in the button click you have to use the newly created action.

HomeFragment button click should be updated as

```
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_editProfile)
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my question. I wanted to navigate from Notifications to Edit Profile, which means that my nav graph is correct. I have two actions from Notifications to Edit profile and vice versa.

Comment: I am now able to navigate as expected! Your inputs plus emirhangulmez's inputs both helped!